# Connect ASP.NET app to gearhost database

Tags: sql, asp.net, database-connection, connection-string

I am trying to connect my asp.net application to the database I just created on www.gearhost.com. 
In web.config, I added

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionName" connectionString="Data Source=mysqlX.gear.host;Initial Catalog=database;User Id=user;Password=pass" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

In the Default.aspx page, I created an asp control:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:connectionName%>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT name from user">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

However, when I run the app, I get the error:
*A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]*

Can you please tell me what to do? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the host name is correct (mysqlX.gear.host). Looks like it is MySQL, not SQL Server.